# Do I need Visual C++ redistributables for my app that I have written in a native win32 project in a Microsoft Visual C++ IDE ( 2005 or later)?

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie, I've heard that Visual C++ redistributable are for apps that are developed in VS C++ IDEs (newer than 6.0 version). But what if I only write applications that are buid in win32 projects, with purely RAW win32 functions (no MFC, no .Net), then do I need them?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/leepa/libctiny.  I use a variant of this in my self-extracting installer to keep the size down.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, [this is possible](http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-the-visual-c-runtime-library/184416623). However, be aware that the CRT provides many conveniences that you may be used to. The entry point will have to be replaced, functions that perform string operation will have to be reimplemented, and even memory management operations like `malloc` and `new` will have to be replaced with the Win32 equivalents (`HeapAlloc` and such). Your other option is to statically link the CRT.

Comment: Thank you, mnistic. Your answer is lots of help for me.